# Check If the Worksheets Name in a Workbook is a Months Name

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with the code below. I found the code online @ StackOverflow I added some lines but the code does not work and I get an error message.

What I'm trying to do is to loop through each worksheet in workbook A. And check if the name of the worksheet is equals to a Month Name. If it does then insert a column in Column A and write the sheets Month Name in Column A cells.
There is data already  in column B:H and each existing month worksheets has dynamic rows. So after the column has been inserted and the sheets name is place in Cells(r,1) then copy the Month Sheets data to Workbook "Consolidated Data". TIA

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 12
        If IsError(MonthName(i, False)) = True Then
        Else
        Set ws = wbYTD.Sheets(MonthName(i, False))
        End If

        With ws
            .Columns(1).Insert
            .Range("A3").Value = (MonthName(i, False))
        End With
    Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function returns `TRUE` when `st` contains a valid month name:

```
Function isMonthName(st As String) As Boolean
  Dim test
  On Error Resume Next
  test = DateValue(st & " 1, 1999")
  isMonthName = IIf(Err, False, True)
End Function
```

---

**Examples:**

- `isMonthName("july")` returns `TRUE`.
- `isMonthName("julyy")` returns `FALSE`.

---

I'm not sure if it will work is all regions but it tests fine for me.

The function simply plugs the string into a string with a day and year ("`____ 1, 1999`") and checks whether it's a valid date using the [`DateValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datevalue-function) function.  If it doesn't work in your region, just change that you probably just need to change the string to represent your area' "long date".